# Search vertically in autolisp

Tags: excel, autolisp

I have a problem reading data from exel by using autlisp.

I am trying to create an Autolisp that after loading a layer name from polines will search for it in exel in column B and then after finding it will copy the value from column G.
It will add this value to another variable and then no matter.

Currently I am getting an error
; error: ActiveX Server returned an error: Type mismatch

```
(defun c:ee ()
    
      (setq lista_kablowa (vlax-get-or-create-object "Excel.Application"))
      (setq plik (vlax-get-property lista_kablowa 'Workbooks))
      (setq workbook (vlax-invoke-method plik 'Open "C:\\Users\\x.y\\Desktop\\ILOSC KABLI\\lista_kablowa.xlsx"))
      (setq sheet (vlax-invoke-method workbook 'Worksheets 1))
    
      (setq obj (ssget '((0 . "LWPOLYLINE"))))
      (if obj
          (progn
            (setq nN 0)
            (setq SN 0)
            (setq TRC 0)
            (setq STER 0)
            (setq count (sslength obj))
            (setq i 0)
            (repeat count
              (setq entity (ssname obj i))
              (setq layer (cdr (assoc 8 (entget entity))))
            ;NEW WRONG CODE
              (setq warstwa (vlax-invoke-method sheet 'Cells i 2))
              (setq nazwa_warstwy (vlax-get-property warstwa 'Value))
              (cond ((vl-string-search "C00-ENN-" layer)
                     (setq wartość (vlax-get-property (vlax-invoke-method sheet 'Cells i 7) 'Value))
                     (setq nN (+ nN wartość)))
                    ;ADDITION CODE
                    ((vl-string-search "C00-ESN-" layer)
                     (setq SN (1+ SN)))
                    ;ADDITION CODE
                    ((vl-string-search "C00-STER-" layer)
                     (setq STER (1+ STER)))
                    ;ADDITION CODE
                    ((vl-string-search "C00-5" layer)
                     (setq TRC (1+ TRC))))
              (setq i (1+ i)))
    
            (vlax-invoke-method workbook 'Close :vlax-true)
            (vlax-invoke-method lista_kablowa 'Quit)
    
            (setq text "")
            (if (> nN 0)
                (setq text (strcat (itoa nN) "xnN")))
            (if (> SN 0)
                (setq text (strcat text "+" (itoa SN) "xSN")))
            (if (> TRC 0)
                (setq text (strcat text "+" (itoa TRC) "xTRC")))
            (if (> STER 0)
                (setq text (strcat text "+" (itoa STER) "xSTER")))
    
            (command "TEXT" (getpoint "\nPick a point: ") 1.8 0 text)
          )
        (alert "Nie znaleziono obiektów.")
      )
      (princ)
    )
```